# draw circle on MKMapview in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ellipse

I am trying to draw circles around the current location on MKMapview.I tryied many codes but however no success. can any one suggest any links which should I refer. I am new to Iphone so dont have much knowledge about Quartz 2D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think the simplest method to achieve your goal would be to use a custom PNG image with transparency and set the image property of a [`MKAnnotationView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKAnnotationView) that you add to your current `MKMapView`.